setup azure site recovery with VM replication in azure using python automation runbook
Iam new to working python in azure. i need to setup azure site recovery with vms replication using python automation runbook. i tried multiple ways to get the information to enable vm replication using python. But iam unable to find it. Please suggest some how to achieve my goal.
Referred this link for power shell :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-powershell. its working fine.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"Have you tried using Python code for the same requirement?

"Here is the Python code to enable backup for the VM in the Recovery Services Vault.

Note: You can customize the code as per your requirement. In my case, I created a VM and a Recovery Services Vault, and then enabled backup in the the same run.

For the automation runbook, you can use the same code in the automation account.
import os
import random
import re
import string

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.activestamp import RecoveryServicesBackupClient
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.activestamp.models import BackupRequestResource, BackupRequest, \
    ProtectedItemResource
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservices import RecoveryServicesClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient


credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "83a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
recovery_services_client = RecoveryServicesClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
recovery_services_backup_client = RecoveryServicesBackupClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

GROUP_NAME = "demorg"
LOCATION = 'centralus'
NETWORK_NAME = "networknamex"
VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME = "testvm"
SUBNET_NAME = "subnetx"
INTERFACE_NAME = "interfacex"
your_password = 'A1_' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(8))

RS_VAULT = 'my-vault'

def main():
    # Create resource group
    resource_group = resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, {'location': LOCATION})

    # Create virtual network
    network_client.virtual_networks.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        NETWORK_NAME,
        {
            'location': LOCATION,
            'address_space': {
                'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']
            }
        }
    ).result()

    subnet = network_client.subnets.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        NETWORK_NAME,
        SUBNET_NAME,
        {'address_prefix': '10.0.0.0/24'}
    ).result()

    # Create network interface
    network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        INTERFACE_NAME,
        {
            'location': LOCATION,
            'ip_configurations': [{
                'name': 'MyIpConfig',
                'subnet': {
                    'id': subnet.id
                }
            }]
        }
    ).result()

    # Create virtual machine
    vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME,
        {
            "location": LOCATION,
            "hardware_profile": {
                "vm_size": "Standard_D2_v2"
            },
            "storage_profile": {
                "image_reference": {
                    "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
                    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                    "version": "latest",
                    "offer": "WindowsServer"
                },
                "os_disk": {
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "managed_disk": {
                        "storage_account_type": "Standard_LRS"
                    },
                    "name": "myVMosdisk",
                    "create_option": "FromImage"
                },
                "data_disks": [
                    {
                        "disk_size_gb": "1023",
                        "create_option": "Empty",
                        "lun": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "disk_size_gb": "1023",
                        "create_option": "Empty",
                        "lun": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "os_profile": {
                "admin_username": "testuser",
                "computer_name": "myVM",
                "admin_password": your_password,
                "windows_configuration": {
                    "enable_automatic_updates": True  # need automatic update for reimage
                }
            },
            "network_profile": {
                "network_interfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/" + SUBSCRIPTION_ID + "/resourceGroups/" + GROUP_NAME + "/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/" + INTERFACE_NAME + "",
                        # "id": NIC_ID,
                        "properties": {
                            "primary": True
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ).result()
    print(f"Create virtual machine:{vm}")

    # Create Recovery Services vault
    recovery_services = recovery_services_client.vaults.begin_create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        RS_VAULT,
        {
            "location": LOCATION,
            "sku": {
                "name": "standard"
            },
            "properties": {}
        }
    ).result()
    print(f"Create recovery services vault:\n{recovery_services}")


    # Configure backup parameters
    filter_string = "backupManagementType eq \'AzureIaasVM\'"
    protectable_item = recovery_services_backup_client.backup_protectable_items.list(RS_VAULT, GROUP_NAME, filter_string)
    arm_id = list(protectable_item)[0].id
    container_uri = re.search('(?<=/protectionContainers/)[^/]+', arm_id).group()
    item_uri = re.search('(?<=protectableItems/)[^/]+', arm_id).group()

    backup_props = {'protected_item_type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',
                    'source_resource_id': f'/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/{GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME}',
                    'policy_id': f'/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/{GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{RS_VAULT}/backupPolicies/DefaultPolicy',
                    }

    # Azure VM enable backup
    backup = recovery_services_backup_client.protected_items.create_or_update(
        vault_name=RS_VAULT,
        resource_group_name=GROUP_NAME,
        fabric_name='Azure',
        container_name=container_uri,
        protected_item_name=item_uri,
        parameters=ProtectedItemResource(properties=backup_props)
    )

    # Start backup
    backup_now = recovery_services_backup_client.backups.trigger(
        vault_name=RS_VAULT,
        resource_group_name=GROUP_NAME,
        fabric_name='Azure',
        container_name=container_uri,
        protected_item_name=item_uri,
        parameters=BackupRequestResource(properties=BackupRequest(object_type="AzureIaaSVM"))
    )
    print('Finish')

    # clean deployment
    recovery_services_backup_client.protected_items.delete(
        vault_name=RS_VAULT,
        resource_group_name=GROUP_NAME,
        fabric_name='Azure',
        container_name=container_uri,
        protected_item_name=item_uri,
    )
    recovery_services_client.vaults.delete(resource_group_name=GROUP_NAME, vault_name=RS_VAULT)
    print('Delete RS vault')

    resource_client.resource_groups.begin_delete(resource_group_name=GROUP_NAME)
    print('Delete Resource Group')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Output:

Reference:  Getting started - Managing Recovery Services Backup using Azure Python SDK

Thanks for sharing the script. But iam looking for enable multiple VM's replication is using azure automation runbook with python SDK in azure platform

You can specify the VM names in paremeter with  loop to iterate over multiple VMs for the replication processVM_NAMES = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"] and use the same code in runbook.

we need python script to setup site recovery with enable multiple vm replication

You can customize the above Python code to enable site recovery for multiple VMs with a loop.

above code for backup not for replication
